# Why can I connect to Wi-Fi with 2nd gen Amazon IoT button but not 1st gen buttons?

Tags: aws-iot, amazon-iot-button

I have three Amazon IoT buttons. One is model JK29LP (2nd gen) and two are model JK76PL (1st gen). I had the mac addresses for all three buttons whitelisted for our local Wi-Fi network.

I was able to set up my 2nd gen button from the AWS mobile app without a problem.  My 1st gen buttons I have not been able to get connected to the network using the AWS mobile app or by manually creating a thing, certificate, and policy for the buttons through the AWS IoT console.

For the 1st gen buttons I am able to successfully discover the button, connect to the button access point, and navigate to the ConfigureMe page at http://192.168.0.1/index.html. When I try to connect to the designated WiFi network with the password I have for each mac address, each button blinks red three short times.  From the [IoT button FAQ page](https://aws.amazon.com/iotbutton/faq/), it looks like this means the error I am getting is related to connecting to my Wi-Fi network.

The last long paragraph of [this article](https://mpetroff.net/2015/05/amazon-dash-button-teardown/) gives a little insight into how the button goes about connecting to Wi-Fi. [This article](https://mpetroff.net/2016/07/new-amazon-dash-button-teardown-jk29lp/) gives similar detail about the new button, but I don't see any difference between how the two buttons connect to WiFi that explains why I'm able to successfully connect on my network using the 2nd gen button but not the 1st gen.  Any ideas on what the difference is between these that could be causing this issue?

Comment: This is, essentially a debugging question, and as such it requires more information.  Particularly, you need to state the the type of encyption used by the problem network.  You almost might want to try changing that, or the password especially if it is in any way odd.  And you should include how far the devices were from the access point.